# Case em Sub Select SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Boa tarde,
Estou com problema para fazer um case em uma subquery.

Eu preciso trazer uma informação chamada id_pedido da tabela sf_vendas_boleto, porém quando a mesma vier NULL eu preciso trazer o id_pedido da tabela sf_vendas_online.

Segue trecho com problema...

```
(case when  MAX(id_pedido) is null then (select MAX(id_pedido) from sf_vendas_online where id_venda = sf_vendas.id) else MAX(id_pedido) end id_pedido) id_pedido,
```

SEGUE A QUERY COMPLETA

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sf_vendas.id desc) as row,sf_vendas.*,P.nome_pessoa,P.sobrenome_pessoa,
    ISNULL((SELECT top 1 descricao_documento FROM sf_vendas_parcelas INNER JOIN sf_tipo_documento ON sf_tipo_documento.id = sf_vendas_parcelas.tipo_documento WHERE id_venda = sf_vendas.id),'CORTESIA') id_vendas_parcelas, 
    (select MAX(bol_data_parcela) from sf_vendas_boleto where id_venda = sf_vendas.id) bol_data_parcela, 
    (select MAX(id) from sf_vendas_boleto where id_venda = sf_vendas.id) bol_id, 
    (select SUM(quantidade) from sf_vendas_itens where id_venda = sf_vendas.id) quantidade, 
    (select SUM(valor_bruto) from sf_vendas_itens where id_venda = sf_vendas.id) valor_bruto, 
    (select SUM(valor_desconto) from sf_vendas_itens where id_venda = sf_vendas.id) valor_desconto, 
    (select MAX(data_pagamento) from sf_vendas_parcelas where id_venda = sf_vendas.id) data_pagameto, 
    (select SUM(valor_pago) from sf_vendas_parcelas where id_venda = sf_vendas.id) valor_pago, 
    (select sum(valor_bruto - valor_desconto) from sf_vendas_itens where id_venda = sf_vendas.id) valor_total,
    (select MAX(bol_valor) from sf_vendas_boleto where id_venda = sf_vendas.id) bol_valor,        
    (case when  MAX(id_pedido) is null then (select MAX(id_pedido) from sf_vendas_online where id_venda = sf_vendas.id) else MAX(id_pedido) end id_pedido) id_pedido,
    (select MAX(bol_nosso_numero) from sf_vendas_boleto where id_venda = sf_vendas.id) bol_nosso_numero
    from dbo.sf_vendas INNER JOIN sf_pessoa P ON P.id = sf_vendas.pessoa_venda) as x ORDER BY id desc
```

Comment: você pode usar COALESCE() ou então ISNULL()

Comment: Sabe me dizer como ficaria o código?

Comment: COALESCE(sf_vendas_boleto.id_pedido, sf_vendas_online.id_pedido) ou ISNULL(sf_vendas_boleto.id_pedido, sf_vendas_online.id_pedido)

só verifica os nomes das tabelas pq voce repetiu os nomes na sua pergunta

Comment: Eu não compreendi como faria.
Seria algo parecido com isso?

(ISNULL(select MAX(id_pedido) from sf_vendas_online where id_venda = sf_vendas.id, select MAX(id_pedido) from sf_vendas_boleto where id_venda = sf_vendas.id) id_pedido,

Comment: eu respondi com exemplos, da uma olhada (abaixo)

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver com esse código...

```
ISNULL((SELECT MAX(id_pedido) FROM sf_vendas_online where id_venda = sf_vendas.id),(SELECT MAX(id_pedido) FROM sf_vendas_boleto where id_venda = sf_vendas.id)) id_pedido,
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue exemplo do uso das funções ISNULL() e COALESCE()

```
declare @ID_1 int = null
declare @ID_2 int = 17

select ISNULL(@ID_1, @ID_2) teste1, COALESCE(@ID_1, @ID_2) teste2
```

Se você tiver mais condições a serem aplicadas, usa o COALESCE. Por exemplo:

```
declare @ID_1 int = null
declare @ID_2 int = null
declare @ID_3 int = 17

select COALESCE(@ID_1, @ID_2, @ID_3) teste1
```